# DE1-SoC displaying LEDs

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, intel, fpga

I am trying to use the DE1-SoC board to run this program. It is supposed to allow the user to input a character, and return that letter in binary on red LEDs on the board. It uses two functions that take in user input and displays the execution to the terminal. When I run the program, random characters (like å) get output and not regular characters.

Here's my code.

```
#include "JTAG_UART.h"
#include "address_map_arm.h"

int main(void) {
    /* Declare volatile pointers to I/O registers (volatile means that IO load
       and store instructions will be used to access these pointer locations,
       instead of regular memory loads and stores) */
    volatile int * JTAG_UART_ptr = (int *)JTAG_UART_BASE; // JTAG UART address
volatile int * LED_ptr = (int*)LED_BASE;
    char  text_string[] = "\nJTAG UART example code\n> \0";
    char *str, * c;
  //  char *c_ptr=c;

    /* print a text string */
    for (str = text_string; *str != 0; ++str)
        put_jtag(JTAG_UART_ptr, *str);

    /* read and echo characters */
    while (1) {
        c = get_jtag(JTAG_UART_ptr);
         if (c != 0 && c<123 && c>96){
         *LED_ptr = *c ;
         put_jtag(JTAG_UART_ptr, *c);
        }
           // put_jtag(JTAG_UART_ptr, c);
    }
}
```

This is the code for the functions I referenced.

```
#include "JTAG_UART.h"

/*******************************************************************************
 * Subroutine to send a character to the JTAG UART
 ******************************************************************************/
void put_jtag(volatile int * JTAG_UART_ptr, char c) {
    int control;
    control = *(JTAG_UART_ptr + 1); // read the JTAG_UART control register
    if (control & 0xFFFF0000)       // if space, echo character, else ignore
        *(JTAG_UART_ptr) = c;
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Subroutine to read a character from the JTAG UART
 * Returns \0 if no character, otherwise returns the character
 ******************************************************************************/
char get_jtag(volatile int * JTAG_UART_ptr) {
    int data;
    data = *(JTAG_UART_ptr); // read the JTAG_UART data register
    if (data & 0x00008000)   // check RVALID to see if there is new data
        return ((char)data & 0xFF);
    else
        return ('\0');
}
```

Inputting a character like 'a' which is the decimal number 97 in ASCII. Should display itself as 01100001 with each '1' representing itself lit up on the board. As I stated I'm having a logic error, while input is being read 'a' would appear as 00010000

Comment: To begin with, you should drop the "sloppy typing". You definitely never want to use signed `int` type for 32 bit registers, replace that with `uint32_t`. Only use `char` for actual characters, never for raw data - use `uint8_t` for that. Regarding your hex literals, you should end them all with `ul` to ensure that they are always of the same type. Once you've gotten rid of the subtle signed number bug potential, you'll be in a much better position to trouble-shoot the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your compiler did not complain about the assignment of a `char` to a `char*` here: `c = get_jtag(JTAG_UART_ptr);` !?

Comment: My answer does not address @Lundin's criticisms, because they do not address the specific issue you are asking about - but do not ignore them, they address other issues.

Comment: Don't vandalize your questions.  If you want to mark it solved, click the checkmark under the vote arrows on an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `c` as a `char*` when it should clearly be a `char`.

```
char c ;
```

Then loose the `*c` de-references:

```
*LED_ptr = c ;
put_jtag(JTAG_UART_ptr, c);
```

The line:

```
 c = get_jtag(JTAG_UART_ptr);
```

should have issued a warning;  GCC for example outputs:

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

Do not ignore (or disable) warnings; at least don't ignore them then ask a question here without mentioning the warning.